# Drop rows based on same name and same date with different time python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have `pandas` dataframe like this:

```
name     date
john     2021-01-19 06:30:29
tom      2021-03-21 19:30:01
tom      2021-03-21 22:02:34
sam      2021-02-14 13:13:21
sam      2021-02-16 10:15:55
kim      2021-04-01 15:10:44
sam      2021-01-23 13:13:21
sam      2021-02-16 17:11:12
```

Is there any way to drop rows based on same name and same date(even different time)? Doesn't matter keep first/last one.
So the output will like this:

```
name     date
john     2021-01-19 06:30:29
tom      2021-03-21 19:30:01
sam      2021-02-14 13:13:21
sam      2021-02-16 10:15:55
kim      2021-04-01 15:10:44
sam      2021-01-23 13:13:21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column which contains date only and use drop_duplicates() to drop rows with same date, name

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['dateOnly'] = df['date'].dt.date
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name', 'dateOnly'], inplace=True)
df.drop(['dateOnly'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
['john'  ,   '2021-01-19 06:30:29'],
['tom'   ,   '2021-03-21 19:30:01'],
['tom'   ,   '2021-03-21 22:02:34'],
['sam'   ,   '2021-02-14 13:13:21'],
['sam'   ,   '2021-02-16 10:15:55'],
], columns=['name', 'date'])
```

Output:

```
    name    date
0   john    2021-01-19 06:30:29
1   tom     2021-03-21 19:30:01
3   sam     2021-02-14 13:13:21
4   sam     2021-02-16 10:15:55
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a shorter version with `groupby` and `first` (assuming `df['date']` is already a datetime):

```
df.groupby(['name', df['date'].dt.date], as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
   name                date
0  john 2021-01-19 06:30:29
1   kim 2021-04-01 15:10:44
2   sam 2021-01-23 13:13:21
3   sam 2021-02-14 13:13:21
4   sam 2021-02-16 10:15:55
5   tom 2021-03-21 19:30:01
```